# Do NM data type in HL7 message support comma as decimal separator for countries that uses comma in decimal values?

Tags: hl7-v2

I am working with HL7 messages in Sweden locale, but in Sweden they use comma as decimal separator. When Hl7 message will come to my system from Sweden locale will the field with 'NM' (Numeric) data type support comma as decimal?

For example- If the value for one of the field of NM data type is 12.5 if it will come from Sweden region, How will I receive that value in HL7 message, as 12.5 or 12,5 ?

Answer (score 0):

According [hl7.eu](http://www.hl7.eu/refactored/dtNM.html)

Definition: A number represented as a series of ASCII numeric characters consisting of an optional leading sign (+ or -), the digits and an optional decimal point. In the absence of a sign, the number is assumed to be positive. If there is no decimal point the number is assumed to be an integer.